# Multiple alignments with left-aligned text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I would like to achieve the following alignment:

[image]

with equal sign aligned and the term `ar` aligned, as well as the text `and` left-aligned on the second row of the equations.

I tried using `flalign` but there is a weird space before the term `ar`.

[image]

**My MWE:**

```
\begin{flalign*} 
            &&  s_n     &= a +  && ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} &\\ 
\text{and}  &&  rs_n    &=      && ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} + ar^n &
\end{flalign*}
```

Comment: I take it \intertext and \shortintertext (mathtools) are unacceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a simple `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  & & s_n &= a + ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} &\\
 & \text{and} & rs_n &= \phantom{a +{}} ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} + ar^n &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility, to control the space between the text `and` at the margin, and the equations themselves, with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` combined with  `alignat` with three columns:

```
\usepackage{nccmath}
...........
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
        & & s_n &={} & a + ar &+ ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} \\
      & \text{and} &\hspace{3em} rs_n &= &ar & + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} + ar^n
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}
```

Note: if you load `mathtools`, `nccmath` has to be loaded first.
[image]

Comment: Oh! yes. How could I overlook it? Thanks so much for pointing it, @Mico!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `\phantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*} 
            &&  s_n     &= a + ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} &\\ 
\text{and}  &&  rs_n    &= \phantom{ar + } ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} + ar^n &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference with my first solution?

Comment: To be honest, there is no difference. When I posted my answer I didn't soo that there was already an answer, let alone an identical. Our posts must have overlapped with you brine a few seconds faster. I honestly hope this didn't come across as stealing your answer.

Comment: No, I never thought so.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `flalign*`: A simple `align*` environment, with a single `&` alignment point per row, along with a suitable `\phantom` statement gets the job done.

Aside: I don't think it's helpful to place the word "and" very far away from its associated equation. If you believe that a `\quad` distance doesn't create enough separation, try `\qquad`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
 s_n &=           a + ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} \\ 
\text{and}\quad 
rs_n &= \phantom{a+{}}ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^{n-1} + ar^n 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```